# UWP App example with commandbar, splitview and title

Tags: win-universal-app

I am looking for a example code which use top commandbar, splitview with hamburgericon and title of page with backbutton near humbergericon. Something like a MSN Weaher app:

[image]

I am looking exactly the same top bar with title and backbutton and left splitview. Do you know about something like this?

Comment: The same Hamburger menu code available on GitHub [check this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=InVsajohErQ)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Template10](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10) to get an implementation of the SplitView with Burger Icon.

Special consideration about the BackButton : in this sample, this is just a simple button, when clicked you have to call the following code:

```
if (this.Frame.CanGoBack) this.Frame.GoBack();
```

If you plan to implement this feature, be carefull when your application will be executed in tablet mode or running on a mobile phone. In these situations, you have to manage also hardware/soft back button. Please check [Back button navigation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt465734.aspx) documentation.